# Question about nconnected non-bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

going through some online course right now and came across something that baffles me. In the [lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf) on page 158 a connected non-bipartite graph G' and a function are introduced.

> dist(u) = the length of the shortest path from u to v in G'

Where v is some node in V' and then two sets are defined based on whether dist(u) returns an even number, set L, or dist(u) returns an odd number, set R.

Then this the following is merely stated:

> Since G' is not bipartite, there must be a pair of adjacent nodes u1 and u2
>   that are both in L or both in R

It is really not clear to me why this statement is correct.

Can someone explain why this statement is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that every edge is between a vertex in $L$ and a vertex in $R$.

Then the sets $L$ and $R$ are a bipartition of $G'$.

Comment: no problem, it happens to everyone.